# MongoDB Docker Container on AWS ECS using EFS

Tags: mongodb, docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-efs

Is it recommended to have multiple MongoDB Docker containers on the AWS Elastic Container Service (ECS) that share the same AWS Elastic File System (EFS)? Why? Why not?

Comment: Technically possible but EFS has performance overhead. You can instead use other docker storage drivers with local cache to gain more performance.

Comment: Obviously a late response so for future finders: EFS does offer a "Max IO" option that can help some of the overhead you might experience.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on your requirements. Basically, EFS implements NFSv4 protocols. Usually NFS is slower than the block device. Didn't test it. But think EFS performance would be lower than EBS on the same SSD device. You could test your application with MongoDB on EFS. If performance is not a concern, it would be fine to use EFS.